# Get shared dataset with Api

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata

I am trying to get a list of all the shared datasets that shared with me in Google BigQuery with API

I try using `bigquery.projects.list` but the API only bring me my only projects.
How can I get all the datasets that people shared with me via API?

Comment: you can't get this

Comment: why not? how google bigQuery is doing that?

Comment: I think, I am not aware about any publicly available feature/UI where Google actually "is doing that". Can you please point me where you think they do?

Comment: If I share a dataset with other user I can see the dataset in the left projects area...
So I want to know witch Api they using for that feature?

Comment: sorry, i am not sure I got it! you see the dataset that you shared with other user? of course you see it! can you point me to where you see the dataset which someone else shared with you?

Comment: In google bigQuery UI is see it. But I want to get with API all the datasets that shared with me, how can I do that? only with api, without any UI.
I am sure that there is a way to do that because that I see it in BigQuery UI

Comment: bad news - your conclusion on what it is that you see in UI is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

In order to see all the datasets that were shared with you in the UI you have to add its projects to the UI.

For example, in the classic BigQuery UI ([bigquery.cloud.google.com](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com)) you can do it by clicking in the down-facing arrow next to your project, then click "Switch to project" and then "Display project...".

Same wise, in the new BigQuery UI ([console.cloud.google.com/bigquery](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery)) you would have to click "ADD DATA" and then "Pin a Project".

By default you don't get the list of datasets shared with you in the UI and you can't also get this list through a single REST request. As noted in the [datasets.list method](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/list), it is required to specify the Project ID you want to list datasets from.

You may wonder if you could use the [projects.list method](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/list) and then run a REST command for each project you get there, but this would only work for projects' datasets that were granted a role at the project level but not at the dataset level.

---

Therefore, the only way to get the list of all datasets shared with you is by knowing beforehand all the projects that have shared datasets with you and then running a list operation for each one of them.

Comment: so, in short - you can't do this - right? by `this` I mean whatever exactly OP has asked  :o)

Comment: He could do it only if he knows beforehand what projects have granted him access to their datasets. Otherwise then the answer is no, all list operations from the API are designed to work on a per-project basis and the ability to grant access to datasets at the dataset level and not at the project level makes it unattainable to get this list programmatically.

Comment: I prefer not to make any assumptions. OP asked how to get this list through the API, the use case for this requirement is wide enough for it to be for an automatized process and not just because people ignore the projects that granted access to their data sets. I'm just posting possible scenarios for his/her or anyone else's reference.

Comment: read first and third sentence in OP post! no assumptions here! 100% clear! i am not against your answer  - i just want to be clear that whatever exactly user asks - is not possible right now. the rest is just workarounds for particular cases - meantime - your answer is correct for those cases, but not for the exact question!

Comment: The answer nevertheless is the same: "the only way to get the list of all datasets shared with you is by knowing beforehand all the projects that have shared datasets with you and then running a list operation for each one of them".

Comment: I agree with you on that one :o) it is like half empty vs. half full